# firely - how to connect to Azue Fhir service using a C# console app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, fhir-server-for-azure

**Update:**
I managed to solve this using the replies posted. I have appended the actual steps I used below but marked the reply that led to this as the answer.

I have a .Net 8 console app using C# and am trying to connect to an Azure Fhir service (basic add patient, get patient scenario).

The issue is that I can't find any up-to-date/accurate information on how to do so that isn't using Postman other similar approaches.

I am using the Fire.ly HL7.Fhir.R4 (5.5.1) nuget package, and have configured an App Registration in Entra, then using ClientSecretCredential to get the token as follows:

```
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: tenantId, clientId: applicationClientId, clientSecret: secretValue);
AccessToken accessToken = await clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new[] { tokenEndpointAuthority }));
```

I get a response back, then connect using the following:-

```
    var mh = new HttpClientEventHandler();
mh.OnBeforeRequest += (object sender, BeforeHttpRequestEventArgs e) =>
{
    e.RawRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken.Token}" );
};

FhirClient client = new FhirClient( endpoint: endpointAuthority, 
                                    messageHandler: mh, 
                                    settings: new FhirClientSettings { PreferredFormat = ResourceFormat.Json });
```

I appear to get a valid response, then construct a patient object, however, when I call the client create I get access forbidden.

```
client.Create<Patient>(patient)  // FhirOperationException (Forbidden) Authorization Failed.
```

Does anyone have a sample of C# code that gets the token and if possible, some up-to-date instructions setting up the app-registration in entra - in case I have this incorrect.

Also, when I check the access token expiry date, it appears to be set to the datetime that the request was made - is this correct?

My end process: -

1. Create an App Registration in Entra
2. In Entra go to Enterprise Applications and ensure the Service Principal is created (usually has the same name as the app reg)
3. Go to the fhir service and under IAM, add a new role assignment

In step 3 what was happening was happening for me is that when clicking on 'select members', it was only displaying my current users but not any security principals.   I found that I needed to paste in the name of the principal fully before it was displayed and could be selected.

Once this was done, I was able to connect my client using by using both  ADAL and MSAL to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if the service principal **does not have** required RBAC roles under FHIR resource to perform the operation.

I registered one Entra ID application named **`FHIRapp`** and created one **client secret** in it like this:

[image]

When I tried to connect Azure FHIR service without adding RBAC role to service principal, I got **same error** as below:

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to assign proper RBAC role like **FHIR Data Contributor** to the service principal, under your Azure FHIR service like this:

[image]

When I ran the below code again now, I got the **response** with created patient details successfully as below:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;
using Hl7.Fhir.Model;
using Hl7.Fhir.Rest;

class Program
{
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string endpointAuthority = "https://demofhirxxxx.azurehealthcareapis.com/";
        string tenantId = "tenantId";
        string applicationClientId = "appId";
        string secretValue = "secret";
        string tokenEndpointAuthority = "https://demofhirxxxx.azurehealthcareapis.com/.default";

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: tenantId, clientId: applicationClientId, clientSecret: secretValue);

        try
        {
            AccessToken accessToken = await clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new[] { tokenEndpointAuthority }));

            var mh = new HttpClientEventHandler();
            mh.OnBeforeRequest += (object sender, BeforeHttpRequestEventArgs e) =>
            {
                e.RawRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken.Token}");
            };

            FhirClient client = new FhirClient(endpoint: endpointAuthority,
                                               messageHandler: mh,
                                               settings: new FhirClientSettings { PreferredFormat = ResourceFormat.Json });

            var patient = new Patient()
            {
                Name = new List<HumanName>()
                {
                    new HumanName()
                    {
                        Given = new List<string>{"Sridevi"},
                        Family = "Machavarapu"
                    }
                },
                Gender = AdministrativeGender.Female,
                BirthDate = "2000-01-27",
                Identifier = new List<Identifier>()
                {
                    new Identifier()
                    {
                        Value = "123456799"
                    }
                }
            };

            // Create the patient
            var createdPatient = client.Create<Patient>(patient);

            Console.WriteLine($"Patient created with ID: {createdPatient.Id} \n " +
    $"Name: {createdPatient.Name[0].Given.FirstOrDefault()} {createdPatient.Name[0].Family} " +
    $"\n Gender: {createdPatient.Gender} \n BirthDay: {createdPatient.BirthDate}");

        }
        catch (AuthenticationFailedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**References:**

[Configure Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) for Azure API for FHIR | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/healthcare-apis/azure-api-for-fhir/configure-azure-rbac)

[Make Your First FHIR Client - Firely by **Marten Smits**](https://fire.ly/blog/make-your-first-fhir-client-within-one-hour/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply it is appreciated. I am using 'Azure Health Data Services FHIR service' rather than the Fhir API; the process appears to be slightly different - how is the App registration (which contains the shared secret) linked to the Fhir Service?.   Also, when adding RBAC in IAM it asks for a user or group to assign to the role which I don't have as I want to use the shared secret. I've checked the two links provided, but they refer to fhir_client as the members suggesting a group of users (which I dont have).

Comment: You can add RBAC role to user, groups and **service principal** too by searching app registration's name. After adding RBAC role to app registration, it will be linked to FHIR service.

Comment: thanks, I tried looking for a service principal, however, the dialog only allows users  (groups etc are not available).   On an update, I removed the fhir service and the app registration and re-created. I also used MSAL as I understand ADAL is being retired, I now get 'document has no body' when calling client.Create(...)

Comment: Could you include those screenshots on how you are trying to add service principal by editing your question?

Comment: Check this if it helps that includes assigning RBAC roles to service principal under Azure Health Data Services FHIR service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/configure-azure-rbac#assign-roles-for-the-fhir-service

Comment: I think the documentation being used may be out of date.  I'll edit the original post to show.